# Переклад «действующий вулкан» українською

Tags: переклад, from-russian, дієприкметники

Допоможіть перекласти *«действующий вулкан»*. Я переклала як *«діючий вулкан»*, але Вікіпедія вказує, що «активні дієприкметники на `-юч-` українській мові не властиві».

Comment: Слово «діючий» [існує](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=действующий&scope=rusb&dicts=all&highlight=on). Та як воно вам не подобається, завжди можна сказати «активний вулкан».

Comment: @YellowSky Там один словник вказуё: (**устар.**) дію́щий, дію́чий:

Answer (score 5):

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) наводить такі варіанти перекладу дієприкметника *действующий* взагалі і сталого виразу *действующий вулкан* зокрема:

> Действующий – (в акт. действии) що (який) діє, (способн. акт.) чинний,
>   діяльний, дієвий (дійовий), активний; (устар.) дію́щий, дію́чий:
>
> ...
>
> • **действующий вулкан – активний, живий (давн. дію́щий) вулкан**;
>
> ...

Згідно з [гугл-пошуком](https://www.google.com.tr/search?rlz=1C1VFKB_en__709__709&ei=DqH2WuGcHome6ATsp7MQ&q=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD&oq=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10755.13480.0.14741.6.6.0.0.0.0.214.1116.0j4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.945...0i7i30k1j0i13k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i8i7i10i30k1j0i13i30k1.0.Hvex3HxBVcA), вираз "живий вулкан" є досить вживаним серед сучасних мовців.

Answer (score 1):

Ось приклади вживання словосполучення "**діючий вулкан**":

> Єдиний в Україні діючий вулкан знаходиться в селі Старуня,
>   Богородчанського району, Івано-Франківської області ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8)).
>
> Вулкани поділяють на діючі, потенційнодіючі, умовно згаслі і згаслі
>   ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD)).

В [російсько-українському тематичному словнику](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=vg3QBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=kMUQ0Hgjie&sig=XOg30YJhh3ZZCRKlUwQtbTKmmf0&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq07CytbjeAhXik4sKHTDgBG0Q6AEwE3oECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=false) також бачимо переклад "діючий вулкан".

Окрім "[активний вулкан](https://tsn.ua/svit/odin-z-aktivnih-vulkaniv-yevraziyi-plyuyetsya-popelom-na-6-metriv-692594.html)" та "[живий вулкан](http://ipress.ua/ljlive/eyyafyadlayokyudl_zhyvyy_vulkan_v_islandii_shcho_nakoiv_problem_15821.html)" можна ще також сказати "вулкан, який прокинувся" (тоді само-собою стає зрозуміло, що він активний).